# Creating a game with loops that compares a secret number to user input

Tags: java

I was asked to create a mastermind game for school. The project never ran properly and I believe I went about the process in the wrong way. While the assignment is already past due I would like to know where I went wrong. Keep in mind we have still not gone over arrays.

This was the assignment description:
Your program will choose a random 4 digit number as the secret number. Your program must prompt the user to enter a 4 digit number as their guess. The program will respond with a message indicating how many of the digits in the user’s guess are the same as the digit in the same position in the secret number. For example, if the secret number is 3749, and the user’s guess is 9753, then the program would respond with the message You matched 1, because only one of the digits (the 7) in the user’s guess is the same as the digits in the same position in the secret number. The program will allow the user to continue to enter guesses until they guess the correct secret number. After the user has entered the secret number, the program will output a count of the total number of guesses the user took to find the secret number. Then the program will ask the user if they would like to play again. If the user answers “yes”, then the program will choose another random 4 digit number and play continues as described above.

Where was the best place to start for this assignment?
What was the best way to use loops?
How do I select different parts of the secret number?

Any help I can get now will help me catch up in the class.

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment04 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("----- MASTERMIND -----");
        System.out.println("Guess the 4 digit number!");
        int secretNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 1000 + 1);
        
        int usersGuess = 0;
        
        int counter = 0; 
        
        int guessCount = 1;
        
        
        for(int i=0; i<guessCount; guessCount++) {
              System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
              usersGuess = in.nextInt();
              if (String.valueOf(usersGuess).substring(0,0)==String.valueOf(secretNumber).substring(0,0));
              {
                  guessCount ++;
                  counter ++;
                  break;
              if (String.valueOf(usersGuess).substring(1,1)==String.valueOf(secretNumber).substring(1,1));
              {
                  guessCount ++;
                  counter ++;
                  break;
              }
              if (String.valueOf(usersGuess).substring(2,2)==String.valueOf(secretNumber).substring(2,2));
              {
                  guessCount ++;
                  counter ++;
                  break;
              }
              if (String.valueOf(usersGuess).substring(3,3)==String.valueOf(secretNumber).substring(3,3));
              {
                  guessCount ++;
                  counter++;
                  break;
              }
              System.out.println("You matched " + guessCount);
              if(counter==4);
              {
                  System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed the right number in " + counter + "guesses");
                  System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (Yes/No)");
              }
            }
                
         
    }
}
}
```

This is all I was able to come up with.

Comment: I would suggest you to use `equals()` instead of `==` when you need to compare string value,another way is compare directly with `character` type when you want to use `==` operator

Answer (score 0):

So few points

- Your for loop condition (`i < guessCount`) shouldn't be driven by the guess count because it should continue looping until they guess correctly.
  You'd maybe want e.g. a `boolean` named "`continueLooping`" which is true and a `while` condition evaluating that instead of a for loop.
  If the `guessCoun`t (which is summing the number of times the correct digits were aligned) is 4 then "`continueLooping`" would be set to `false` if the user said "No" when asked "Would you like to play again?"
- You shouldn't be breaking after each matched digit. What if the first digit matches and the second digit matches? The break after the first match will stop the second digit ever being counted and the loop will exit
- You want to check the length of their input to make sure it's 4 digits long
- You'd want to use .`equals()` method of `String` rather than == as `String` is a reference type meaning equality is checked using `equals()` not the "==" operator (that is for checking primitive equality or exact reference equality)
- Your "`counter`" should only increment once at the beginning of every loop

Answer (score 0):

You GuessNumberRandomizer is wrong: it will produce 3 digit numbers only. Use this for 4 digits:

```
  int secretNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 10000 + 1);
```

Also, I would suggest using String input or better yet, parse the integer input to String and use charAt() method for comparison instead. Also your usage of break may  create some errors if more than 1 one digit was guessed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop is is not really a good case scenario for a `for` loop. You should use a `while` loop. While will continue iterating, possibly infinitely, until the condition on which it's evaluated is no longer true.

Since your program should continue until the user guesses, or until he guesses right and doesn't want to play anymore, you should have a boolean "flag" which tells the game it should continue the loop. If the game has been won (when the correct guesses in a turn is equal to 4) then you should prompt the user if they want to continue playing, and if they say no, you just turn off the flag and the program exits.

Something like this

```
boolean continue = true;
int correctGuesses;
int numberOfTimesAttempted = 0;
while(continue){
   numberOfTimesAttempted++;
   correctGuesses = 0;
   //Your game logic
   
   if(correctGuesses == 4){
      System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? Y or N");
      char answer = sc.nextLine();
      if(char.toUpper('N'){
         continue = false;
         System.out.println("It took you " + numberOfTimesAttempted + "to win!");
      }
   }
}
```

As some users pointed out, you should also have logic to verify that the user enters strictly 4 numbers.
Rather than comparing each number individually, simply convert the number to a char array and create a for loop that iterates through it. if the char at the current index is equal to the one in the secret number, increase the number of guess counts.
At the end of each loop, print the number of correct guesses. If number of guesses is 4, the user wins.